# jQuery replaceWith() each element with the first

Tags: jquery, replace, element, each, nav

Trying to copy the first `.postNav` on the page and replace all subsequent navs with it. I've got it simplified and the logic seems right, but the function only works when I pass a string, not the element.

JS Fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/cwMhh/1/

HTML:

```
<nav class="postNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#pageHeader">link to header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#one">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#five">link to other posts</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.postNav:gt(0)').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($('.postNav:eq(0)'));
});
```

Comment: "*...the selected element replaces the target by being moved from its old location, not by being cloned."* - http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element:

```
$('.postNav:gt(0)').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('.postNav:first').clone();
});
```

---

For better performance, cache the selectors:

```
var $navs = $('.postNav'),
    $replaceWith = $navs.first();

$navs.not( $replaceWith ).replaceWith(function () {
    return $replaceWith.clone();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var replaceHTML = $('.postNav:first').html();
$('.postNav:gt(0)').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith(replaceHTML);
});
```