# jQuery find which child is active and update other sections

Tags: jquery, nav

Multiple nav sections all with the same links. The active section is shown in the first nav via an active class (`.active`). I'd like to highlight the same link in the subsequent nav sections.

Originally, I used a cloning method (credit due to you fine people, [jQuery replaceWith() each element with the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362175/jquery-replacewith-each-element-with-the-first)) and although it worked perfectly, it interfered with some other functions (because it removes the original elements from the page and replaces them).

**So, I need to figure out another, clever way to check the active class of the first section, find the matching links in the subsequent sections, and apply the class.**

I'm thinking something like this... but something efficient and less ugly. The answer below *does* work.

HTML:

```
<nav class="postNav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#pageHeader">link to header</a></li>
        <li><a href="#one">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four">link to other posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#five">link to other posts</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
var navs   = $('.postNav'),
    first  = navs.first(),
    active = first.find('.active a').attr('href'),
    anchrs = navs.not(first);

anchrs.find('li').removeClass('active');
anchrs.find('a[href=' + active + ']').parent().addClass('active');
```

UPDATE

---

Maybe by seeing which child in the index is active? Then I don't need to filter by the anchor...

UPDATE + Final Answer

---

My Selector cached version of jfriend's answer:

```
var nav   = $('.postNav'),
first = nav.filter(':eq(0)'),
notF  = nav.filter(':gt(0)'),
index = first.find('.active').index();

notF.each(function(){
    $(this).find('li').removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: you mean .active class can be any of the 6 li's and you need to find the link of that li's anchor in other navs and assign .active class to them.Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using the index position of an `li` within its `ul` and jQuery's `.index()` and `.eq()` makes that easier:

```
var index = $(".postNav .active").index();
$(".postNav ul").each(function() {
    $(this).children("li").removeClass("highlight").eq(index)
        .not(".active").addClass("highlight");
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dWaCn/

This works as follows:

- Finds the active element and get its index relative to its siblings
- Find all the postNav ul tags
- Find all the li children in each one of those
- Remove any previous "highlight" class
- Get the matching index sibling
- Remove the active one so we don't change it
- Add the highlight class

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class to each li element:

```
<nav class="postNav">
  <ul>
    <li class="header active"><a href="#pageHeader">link to header</a></li>
    <li class="one"><a href="#one">link to other posts</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#two">link to other posts</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#three">link to other posts</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#four">link to other posts</a></li>
    <li class="five"><a href="#five">link to other posts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BaL8/) seems to meet your requirements. The concern I see is if you have multiple classes assigned to those li elements (other than 'active') which would cause problems relying on $(this).attr('class');